# SpriteView is returning the wrong frame information

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I need some help with the `SpriteView`, which I wanted to use for the first time but it broke my old code since the `frame` is only zero. But see by your self:

I have the following Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

And im my scene I have:

[image]

And then my custom class:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print(frame)
    }
}
```

And the result is:
(-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

And not as expected:
(-375.0, -667.0, 750.0, 1334.0)

Whats is wrong here? If I use the same `Scene` via the 'old' way in a `UIViewController`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I like the question and probably are related to transformations made by SwiftUI to configure the screen size, this is not the final solution, but maybe you can use:

```swift
import SpriteKit

class MyScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print(view.frame)
    }

    override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
        print(#function)
        print(oldSize)
        print(self.size)
    }

}
```

and get this outout:

```
didChangeSize(_:)
(750.0, 1334.0)
(750.0, 1334.0)
...
didChangeSize(_:)
(750.0, 1334.0)
(0.0, 0.0)
didChangeSize(_:)
(750.0, 1334.0)
(0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
didChangeSize(_:)
(0.0, 0.0)
(300.0, 400.0)
didChangeSize(_:)
(0.0, 0.0)
(300.0, 400.0)
```

Complete example [here](https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/SwiftUIViewSize/SwiftUIViewSize/MyScene.swift)